# Mongoose ODM multiple nested schema's

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to be able to nest documents that have different schemas. Is this possible without using references?

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you're looking to model?

Comment: @JohnnyHK - Basically I have User model and I have a "profiles" property(array). Then I will have a different schema for each profile type and would like to push them into user.profiles.

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to use the `Mixed` Mongoose type for `profiles` to do that as arrays otherwise can only contain objects of a single schema.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - I just took a quick look at Mixed types. How would you take advantage of schemas(and types) using them? In other words, is Mongoose validation no longer an option on the sub profiles?

Comment: I don't think you could.  I think you'd be better off defining a single schema that's the superset of all potential profile schemas and just use whatever parts of that schema as needed for each profile.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - I thought about that before... looks like I will go that route. If you want to answer the question with your second response, I will mark it answered. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be best off defining a single schema that's the superset of all potential profile schemas and just use whatever parts of that schema as needed for each profile.